# Converting string expression to Integer Value using C#

Tags: c#, string, integer

Sorry if this question is answered already, but I didn't find a suitable answer.
I am having a string expression in C# which I need to convert to an int or decimal value.

For example:

```
string strExp = "10+20+30";
```

the output should be 60.

how shall I do that???

Comment: Should it also handle expressions such as `"10*(20+30)"` (= 500)?

Comment: ya any valid integer or decimal expression

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/f73a413c-de70-43d5-8449-bbc39285a40e

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) : stable, simple, and powerful

Answer (score 8):

Fwiw, there is an expression parser built into the .NET framework.  The [DataTable.Compute()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method uses it:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var expr = "10 + 20 + 30";
        var result = new DataTable().Compute(expr, null);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Beware however that it isn't a very full-featured one.  Simple expressions only, the kind you'd find in a SQL query.

Comment: Expression syntax defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Comment: That can be useful, thanks

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing built into .NET, so you will need to use a mathematical expression parser and use that to get the result.

[Here](http://www.bestcode.com/html/bcparser_net.html) is one. And a [couple](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/matheval.aspx) of [articles](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/MathieuMathParser.aspx).

Comment: I like the codeproject's approach

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to parse the string by separating the numbers and the operators (+,-,*,/, etc.).  The numbers can be converted to integers or decimals using the .TryParse commands (e.g. Int32.TryParse()).  The operators can be handled with a switch statement.  The more complicated the types of expressions you want to be able to handle the harder it's going to be.  You could use recursion to handle sub-expressions in parentheses.

Edit: I was going to find some sample articles but I see that Oded has already posted some.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a scripting library - IronPython (python), cs-script (c#) or even MSScriptControl (VBscript) - you can then pass your string expression to the library for evaluation.

Example using MSScript Control:

using MSScriptControl;

...

ScriptControl ScriptEngine = new ScriptControlClass();

ScriptEngine.Language = "VBScript";

string expr = "10+20+30";

object result = ScriptEngine.Eval(expr);

decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(result);

Comment: A full scripting library can be dangerous and is usually the wrong choice, because that allows for a lot more than simple math expressions.