# convert a small string value containing a condition to code (or best way to evaluate a condition dynamically)?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to validate dynamic conditions. Is there a way to do:

```
string condition = "i == 3"; 

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{ 
    if (condition)
    {
        // condition met
    }
}
```

or is this the wrong approach and there is a better way to dynamically evaluate  a condition ?

Comment: What you want to do is called "eval". It is something normally considered to be **bad**.

Comment: Possible reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556101/evaluate-conditional-expression, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6052640/613130

Comment: Use Roslyn to build a script engine http://www.jayway.com/2015/05/09/using-roslyn-to-build-a-simple-c-interactive-script-engine/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a delegate expression like this, however this wouldnt convert a string to a expression. But maybe this is a approach that you should consider instead?

```
Func<int, bool> condition = i => i == 3;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (condition(i))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfectly ok if there is a limited and pre-known number of possible conditions :-)

Comment: It works fine with the example condition I mentioned (my mistake), but what happens when the condition goes a bit further (i % 3 == 0) ?

Comment: That would work aswell, infact any expression that can be made on a `int` that results in a `bool` would work fine. And if you want to go further you could add more parameters to your delegate.

Comment: @SimonKarlsson the string would not fit in the condition, as you mentioned in your answer. How can that last gap be bridged? what am I missing?

Comment: @hikizume maybe you want to look into dynamic linq