# C#, How to compute an operation string

Tags: c#

i have a string like that

```
str = "4975 + 10 * (LOG(250.6)) - 321.2"
```

i want to compute the result of this operation.
Is there any sort way to do that?

```
// my operation just includes some of operators (,), +, -, *, / , ., 0-9, LOG
// '.' is used for double number
```

Comment: @Rob I do not think that is the short way the OP is thinking of :)

Comment: No there is no short way to do this, you have to parse the string or present a user interface that allows someone to type numbers and press a log, substract, add button, aka a calculator interface than you do not have to parse a string at all

Comment: You can check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18

Comment: Hmm, that duplicate is outdated and also closed, as a dupe of a question that asks specifically for _compilation_. I think this deserves a fresh start. Reopening.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I dunno, answers for this question will be people either suggesting their favorite lexing/parsing libraries or suggesting that OP write his own. Either way, I'd agree with the question getting closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

Use this library will help you to perform math operations in string format

Add this package

Install-Package DynamicExpresso.Core

code example

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var interpreter = new Interpreter();
            var result = interpreter.Eval("4975 + 10 * (LOG(250.6)) - 321.2".Replace("LOG", "Math.Log"));

            Console.WriteLine("result=> " + result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

result=> 4709.03858042462

link for lib https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso

Comment: Thank you. It's really helpful. I even found a feature (working with variables and parameters) that i really need.

Answer (score 1):

Also answered here:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/2859130/1043824

Try [`DataTable.Compute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx)

I do not have a .net box lying around so I cannot confirm whether it can do `log` or not, but I have used it for long algebric expressions.

Basically this is how it goes:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var ans = dt.compute("5 + (7 - 9) / 3");
```

Comment: Yes, but DataTable is limited and unavailable in dotnet core.

Comment: It works well with double number and "+ - * /" operator. But It doesn't work with Log. I get it a exception like this: 

Unhandled Exception: System.Data.EvaluateException: The expression contains undefined function call Log().