# C# can't convert float to string

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I'm making a simple calc and have trouble. The label text cant be float. How to fix it? (the label is a **equal**)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string firstnum;
    string secondnum;
    string equalnum;
    float firstnumf;
    float secondnumf;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        equalnum = firstnumf + secondnumf;
        equal.Text = equalnum;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string firstnum = richTextBox1.Text;
        string secondnum = richTextBox2.Text;
        float firstnumf = float.Parse(firstnum);
        float secondnumf = float.Parse(secondnum);
    }
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: equal.Text = $"{equalnum}";

Comment: Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'string'

Comment: @ThomasKoelle anyways show the error CS0029

Comment: @csharpbeginner the error message belong into the question. You can [edit] your question

Comment: use `float.tryparse`

Comment: @davidsbro - That's getting a `float` from a `string`. OP needs the opposite.

Comment: There are so many errors in that code that i can only suggest to you that you debug your code an see yourself what is happening. When you get it to compile. firstnumf, secondnumf are different variables in Form1_Load and button1_Click. You can't simply expect that the text in your rtf textboxes can be expressed as floats. When you want to show the value in a textbox you need to cast the float back to string.

Comment: Are you trying to create a [math expression evaluator in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859111/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it once completely new, "tb_" are the 2 textboxes, if there are still questions. Then ask

```
private void bttn_calc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Create 2 double´s (is similar to float)
    double firstnum, secondnum;

    //Turns a text into a double number
    firstnum = Convert.ToDouble(tb_firstnum.Text);
    secondnum = Convert.ToDouble(tb_secondnum.Text);

    //Adds the 2 doubles and makes them into a string
    equal.Text = (firstnum + secondnum).ToString();
}
```

Comment: do you changed any variables? 
Error CS0103 The name 'tb_firstnum' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Yes I have created 2 "TextBoxes", of course you have to name them that way, or rename them. And please don't use "richTextBox" like you did.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/20ivs7u

Comment: so i replaced rtb with tb and it's dosen't do anything

Comment: Yes, otherwise you can not access and use them

Comment: if you can, send me solution please

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jJ3qRpua_3Gn6uq0yh8_9wETALU-yqd-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: here is my vs project

Comment: Thanks. You do not mind if i take your project but change it?

Comment: Everything is okay, if it helps you, why not :D for further questions just ask

Comment: Ok. thanks for investing your time.it's helpful.

Comment: You're welcome, have fun with C# :)

Comment: btw. you can exchange the "+" with "*" or "/" or "-", just try it out :D

Comment: so i wanna made with operators + * / - :D

Answer (score 0):

Make your "equalnum" into a float

```
float equalnum;
```

And let it convert to a string at the end

```
equal.Text = equalnum.ToString();
```

Comment: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: do you write "1.5+1.5" or "1,5+1,5" as an example ?

Comment: I typing like  1.5+1.5

Comment: and you write the result in a float ? or in a string?

Comment: write in string

Comment: No you have to store it in a float and then transform it into a string afterwards

Comment: `float firstNum, secondNum, result;`
`result = firstNum + secondNum;`
`equal.Text = result.ToString();`

Comment: can i send you visual studio solution and you check what's wrong?

Comment: I will do that.

Comment: then send you?.

Comment: just create "Add Another Answer" with the whole file and i copy paste that

Comment: download the solution please from google disk [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XaOfiLMRc9F6OIX45UyOJ1yK36zTLYzn/view?usp=sharing)