# Interpreting Mathematical Expressions ... syntax of constant*variable

Tags: java, math, graph, expression

How do I interpret a mathematical expression such as:

`x^2+8x+16`

into a code that Java understands such as

`x*x+8*x+16`

?

I know that just parsing the first code using a `ScriptEngine` won't work because it doesn't know how to properly evaulate 8x. What do I do!??

Comment: define your own parsing rules. use regular expressions to parse the string. and combine them according to your business logic.

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252895/convert-mathematical-string-to-int/3252967 ? It's about evaluation, but the libs might work for you as well...

Comment: You could roll your own parser. If the expression cannot contain parentheses, then it's 1) split by `+` and `-`, 2) split by `*`,`/` and a digit-alpha boundary, 3) split by a `^`

Comment: An **expression tree** may be of assistance to you.

Comment: Write a context-free grammar for mathematical expressions (regular expressions won't suffice once you have parentheses), then generate a parser for it using some tool. For bonus points you can try to parse `3 sin x cos^2 x`.