# Library to Parse a string as a formula, that works with Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, string, windows-phone-7, formula

Are there any .NET libraries out there that will parse a string as a formula?

ie; "if the user inputs "(2 +5) * 2", the library will be able to work out the calculation?

Edit:Preferably something that will work with Windows Phone 7 without too much fiddling would be nice!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string expression to Integer Value using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607798/converting-string-expression-to-integer-value-using-c)

Comment: Changed the title to reflect the specifics of the actual question. NCalc will not work with WP7. Not without a lot of fiddling anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted source code for one that supports expressions, variables and functions.

You can see it at http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/a-c-expression-evaluator.

Comment: Thank you, I'm about to try it, but do you think there will be too much hassle using this with windows phone 7?

Comment: @Doozer1979: I haven't done any windows phone programming. But it's just straight C# so I'm not sure why it would be a problem.

Comment: Works great, straight out of the box. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

[NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) is a fairly nice library that will parse mathematical expressions in .NET code.

Edit - [New location on Github.](https://github.com/sheetsync/NCalc)

Comment: Lovely. That looks like just the ticket. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the library tip. I guess i should have specified in my post i need it to work with WP7. Edited now.

Comment: @Doozer1979: Heh, true - FYI - that's going to be a lot more difficult to find.  A lot of the common techniques parsers use don't work in SL.

Comment: Unfortunately, NCalc does not work for Windows Phones.

Comment: @rishiJasapara When I posted this, WP wasn't a requirement or in the tags :) was added later, but this works great for most other options

Comment: I agree @ReedCopsey. Works for all other options. :)

Answer (score 0):

Due to possible complexities, I would recommend starting with a web API - WolframAlpha recently [opened theirs](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/documentation.html) and it works great. As a side effect, your application will have to be constantly connected to an active network.

Comment: And for my particular mobile phone application, that's an absolute no-no. Thank you for the suggestion anyway.