# How to use ncalc in a wp7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, ncalc

i am new to wp7 programming and c# and i want to use a mathematical parser for my app.
I found [ncalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) that everyone says it works great for windows phone,
but i don't know how to use it inside my app.I have downloaded the binaries and i added them in my app but when i use a simple expression like this:
  Expression e = new Expression("2 + 3 * 5");
  Debug.Assert(17 == e.Evaluate());
it gives me a bunch of errors.Someone who have used ncalc could tell me how he made it work?

I searched the internet but i couldn't find something.Please help me...

Comment: Download the 'binaries' from the ncalc site, then follow this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually having a similar issue (trying ncalc) and basically it seems like you can't use a .Net runtime with the windows phone/silver light project. You'll need to get the source code and recompile under a windows phone class library project.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get this working yet since ncalc source code uses another dll antlr3.runtime with the same issue. Running in circles. If i find another way or anyone has any ideas or links please post.

[stack overflow link on the same issue by someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484359/build-a-net-dll-to-wp7)

Comment: Check out an alternative here by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279744/library-to-parse-a-string-as-a-formula-that-works-with-windows-phone-7/12083551#12083551  http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/a-c-expression-evaluator.