# Build a .NET dll to WP7

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, dll

How can I port a C# dll to WP7?

I have the .dll source code successfully building on desktop but when I try to reference the dll on a WP7 project I get the following error:

> Reference cannot be added to c:\path\to\my.dll because it was not built using
>   the Windows Phone runtime. Windows Phone projects will work only with
>   Windows Phone assemblies.

Is there an easy way to build it using Windows Phone runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a `Windows Phone Library` project, copy source codes to it and resolve all errors that appears. And than you can reference this `dll` from `Windows Phone` project

Comment: I was hoping for some kind of magic converter, but I ended up doing what you said

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to take a look at the Portable Class Libraries stuff from Microsoft - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx - which allows you to compile a DLL up to work for WP7, Silverlight, .Net Framework or XBOX360

I have used it for a .Net WCF service and WP7 projects to share a common DLL.

There are a few things to look out for, in that there are some unsupported assemblies, but in the whole it covers most of what is needed.