# How can I connect MongoDB.Bson.dll and MongoDB.Driver.dll to Windows Phone project?

Tags: mongodb, windows-phone-7, mongodb-.net-driver

I use MongoDb in my Windows Phone project, and I want to connect MongoDB.Bson.dll and MongoDB.Driver.dll. But I have error "Can not add a link because the project was not built with runtime Windows Phone. Projects Windows Phone can only work with assemblies Windows Phone". I add with button Add reference.. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe that can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484359/build-a-net-dll-to-wp7

Comment: Darin, thank for the link! Sorry, I don't understand which code I need copy? What do after created new Windows Phone Library project?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151351/how-can-i-use-mongodb-in-windows-phone-project. There is no MongoDB driver for Windows Phone, you need to wrap your MongoDB with a server-side API and make the Windows Phone app communicate with the API.